# Colas en C++ y sus funciones básicas

Tags: c++

Estoy trabajando con colas en C++ y ya he definido las funciones básicas de esta, ahora lo que quiero es poder mostrar todos los elementos que hay dentro de ella, pero estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de definir el método, si me pudieran orientar un poco sobre cómo definir ese método.
Les dejo lo que he hecho hasta ahora:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class NodoEntero{//CLASE NODOENTERO//
    private:
    int valor;
    NodoEntero *siguiente;

    public:
    NodoEntero(int valor){
        this->valor=valor;
        this->siguiente=NULL;
    }
    //METODOS SET Y GET//
    void setValor(int valor){
         this->valor=valor;
    }
    void setSiguiente(NodoEntero*siguiente){
         this->siguiente=siguiente;
    }   
    int getValor(){
        return valor;
    }
    NodoEntero* getSiguiente(){
        return siguiente;
    }
};//FIN CLASE//

class Cola{
    private:
        NodoEntero *frente;
        NodoEntero *final;
    public:
    Cola(){//CONSTRUCTOR//
        this->frente=NULL;
        this->final=NULL;
    }

    bool estaVacio(){
        return frente=NULL;
    }   

    int obtenerValor(){
        return frente->getValor();
    }   

    void meter(int valor){
        NodoEntero *nuevoNodo = new NodoEntero(valor);

        if(estaVacio()){
           frente=nuevoNodo;
           final=nuevoNodo; 
        }else{
           final->setSiguiente(frente);
           final=nuevoNodo;
        }
    }

    int sacar(){
         NodoEntero *apuntadorNodo= frente;
         int valor=frente->getValor();
         frente=apuntadorNodo->getSiguiente();
         delete (apuntadorNodo);
         return valor;
    }

    void mostrar(){
         NodoEntero *apuntadorNodo=frente;
         while(apuntadorNodo!=NULL){
              cout<<" "<<apuntadorNodo->getValor();
              apuntadorNodo=apuntadorNodo->getSiguiente();
         }
    }
};
```

El error que estoy teniendo al llamar a `mostrar( )` es que entro en un bucle infinito, y no para al llegar al último elemento de la lista.

Comment: En futuras preguntas, no olvides explicar con el máximo detalle posible **cual es el error** que estás teniendo. Facilita que otros te ayuden :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes 2 fallos:

```
bool estaVacio( ) {
  return frente = NULL;
}
```

Eso que haces es una **asignación**. Para comparar, sería

```
return frente == NULL;
```

El otro fallo es:

```
void meter( int valor ) {
  NodoEntero *nuevoNodo = new NodoEntero( valor );

  if( estaVacio( ) ) {
    frente = nuevoNodo;
    final = nuevoNodo; 
  } else {
    final->setSiguiente( frente );
    final = nuevoNodo;
  }
}
```

Lo que haces en el `else` es crear una lista *circular*. Los nodos se apuntan *en bucle* unos a otros, haciendo imposible que se pueda recorrer.

Lo correcto sería

```
} else {
  final->setSiguiente( nuevoNodo );
  final = nuevoNodo;
}
```

Comment: Mas que un ciclo infinito sera una lista circular, no?? Que parece que el programa se va a quedar atascado en el `else`

Comment: jejeje ... tienes razón. Lo cambio. Gracias por el *toque* :-)

Comment: Gracias, tomaré en cuenta sus sugerencias y haré las respectivas correcciones ;)